# Pointer typecasting in c

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I am writing an implementation of graphs in C language. I came across a situation where I am not able to figure out the reason for the way the compiler is behaving with a pointer typecast warning. 
Here are the structures;

```
#define MAXV 10 
typedef struct {
    int y;
    int weight;
    struct edgenode *next;
} edgenode;


typedef struct {
   edgenode *edge[MAXV+1];
   int degree[MAXV+1];
   // other info of graph
} graph;

// operation in some other function
p->next = g->edge[x];
```

I got a pointer typecast warning[enabled by default] when I do this kind of operation.

I was not able to remove this warning even after trying to typecast with every possible cast.
Finally I made a code change in the structure and suddenly the warning was gone.
The structure code change was this:-

```
typedef struct edgenode {   // note that I have added structure name here
    // same as above definition
} edgenode;

// operation in some other function
p->next = g->edge[x];
```

Now the warning is gone and code runs without any warnings.

I do not understand **why** is this happening; can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
typedef struct {
    int y;
    int weight;
    struct edgenode *next;
} edgenode;
```

It is not clear what type `struct edgenode *next;` is referring to (it doesn't matter; somewhere, presumably, there's a `struct edgenode` defined), but it is not this structure because it has no tag.  You need:

```
typedef struct edgenode
{
    int y;
    int weight;
    struct edgenode *next;
} edgenode;
```

Now the pointer refers to another structure of this same type. So, the fix you found was the correct fix for your problem.

Remember: a `typedef` is an alias (alternative name) for an existing type.  You created a type name `edgenode`, but you had not defined the type `struct edgenode`.  You don't have to fully define a structure type before you create pointers to it; this can be a good way of creating 'opaque types'.

The other way to define things is:

```
typedef struct edgenode edgenode;

struct edgenode
{
    int y;
    int weight;
    edgenode *next;
};
```

This says that the type name `edgenode` is an alias for a `struct edgenode`; the structure definition then tells the compiler what a `struct edgenode` looks like.

Comment: But i don't get the warning until i do that operation.I think the compiler should raise the warning when it first see the `struct edgenode *next;` in the structure definition itself, why is that i get the warning only when it encounters the operation in the code below.

Comment: No: the compiler can't.  It is entirely legitimate to write the code you did — even though it is obviously not what you wanted.  You could have had a `struct pokemon *next;` in there without any further mention of `struct pokemon` in the header. It would compile OK; it is only when you try to use the structure member that you run into problems.

Comment: "somewhere, presumably, there's a struct edgenode defined" -- no,  struct edgenode is an incomplete type, which doesn't get a warning unless the type needs to be complete when referenced, as here.